# How are double precision floats stored in memory?

Tags: gcc, riscv

I would like to know how double-precision numbers are organized in memory.

Say that I want to write 16.55 (0xd40308cccccccccc) to a 2-way interleaved 32-bit memory module, which one of the following would be the correct organization?

mem 0 0xD40308CC
mem 1 0xCCCCCCCC

or

mem 0 0xCCCCCCCC
mem 1 0xD40308CC

RISCV-GCC seems to produce the latter, but I'd like to read more about this, any advice is greatly appreciated!

-Edit: formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RISC-V is little-endian (by default), the bits to the right are stored at earlier memory addresses.
You can find this information in https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf.